How can we sketch 3D experimental Optical setups with Latex?
I want to sketch 3D experimental Optical setups with Latex. I inserted two examples here, but unfortunately, I do not have any code for them and do not know how to sketch these 3D images. Please let me know if you have any ideas.



why would you use latex for such an image?

You can see the pst-optexp manual with texdoc pst-optexp but it the manual suggests makes line sketches like this not annotated photographs like you show.

@DavidCarlisle Thank you for your comment. I can sketch 2D setups but I am looking for 3D ones.

but what you are showing isn't a sketch but a photo isn't it?

include the photo with \includegraphics{} and then annotate it using your favourite method. I'd use tikz. @DavidCarlisle would probably use picture.

see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz?noredirect=1&lq=1 for one method.

Related/duplicate: How to draw a coffee cup (because this question asks to draw some arbitrary 3D object)

@DavidCarlisle Yes, it is a photo, but I aim to have a 3D substrate including those optoelectronic objects.

@Reza your question reads as if it asking for pstricks to make a photo-realistic 3D image of the setup, if you are just asking for a 3D line sketch depicting a similar layout as shown in the photo that;s a lot more reasonable thing to ask for but you should edit the question to ask for that
